# I have edited the css for my countdown clock but it is not displayed

Tags: css

I edited the `css` for my `countdown timer` but it didn't show up.

I want to edit the css for each `hour`, `minute`, and `second` cell.

Please help me.

[this is a link](https://demo6.acbb/)

```js
const span = document.getElementById("countdown");
const deadline = new Date();
deadline.setHours(0);
deadline.setMinutes(0);
deadline.setSeconds(0);
function displayRemainingTime() {
 if (deadline < new Date()) deadline.setDate(deadline.getDate() + 1);
 const remainingTime = deadline - new Date();
 const extract = (maximum, factor) => Math.floor((remainingTime % maximum) / factor);
 let seconds = extract(60000, 1000);
 let minutes = extract(3600000, 60000);
 let hours = extract(10800000, 3600000);
 if (hours < 10) { hours = "0" + hours; }
 if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
 if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
 const string = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds remaining`;
 span.innerText = `${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds`;
}
window.setInterval(displayRemainingTime, 1000);
displayRemainingTime();
```

```css
span#minutes {
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

span#hours {
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

span#seconds {
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
<span id="hours"> 00</span> :
<span id="minutes"> 00</span> :
<span id="seconds"> 00</span>
```

Comment: Your `.innerHTML` overwrites the content of the parent `<div>`, so your `<span>` elements no longer exist (and thus are not valid targets). You'll need to only update the individual `<span>` elements. Also, you're missing the closing `}` in each declaration.

Comment: Please help me correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, innerText replace all the content of you `#countdown` element.
The following code works:

```js
const span = document.getElementById("countdown");
const deadline = new Date();
deadline.setHours(0);
deadline.setMinutes(0);
deadline.setSeconds(0);
function displayRemainingTime() {
    if (deadline < new Date()) deadline.setDate(deadline.getDate() + 1);
    const remainingTime = deadline - new Date();
    const extract = (maximum, factor) => Math.floor((remainingTime % maximum) / factor);
    let seconds = extract(60000, 1000);
    let minutes = extract(3600000, 60000);
    let hours = extract(10800000, 3600000);
    if (hours < 10) { hours = "0" + hours; }
    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
    if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
    span.innerHTML = `<span id="hours">${hours}</span> hours <span id="minutes">${minutes}</span> minutes <span id="seconds">${seconds}</span> seconds remaining`;
}
window.setInterval(displayRemainingTime, 1000);
displayRemainingTime();
```

Another thing is, you don't need to add the `span#id-of-the-element`, on CSS the specificity on the hierarchy of it, does not require it, the ID selector is stronger so I suggest you to add simply this:  (added some colors for demo only)

```css
#minutes {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color:green;
}

#hours {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color:blue;
}

#seconds {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color:red;
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle of the example working:
https://jsfiddle.net/fabiangarga/hk428a0n/7/

Comment: No problem, you can mark this answer as the correct one so I can have some points :D, cheers.